# SciPy.Stats.Zscore appears to be calculating the z-score subtly incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scipy.stats

I am trying to calculate z-scores for a dataset using scipy.stats, and am running into a very weird subtle error that I cannot figure out. The code is running, but appears to be producing data that is slightly off, which I am concerned is adversely impacting a PCA that I am running on the normalized dataset.

I have the following data in a list:

```
mylist = [0.565, 0.629, 0.687, 0.797, 0.56, 0.722]
```

I run the following commands to Z-score normalize the data using scipy.stats:

```
import scipy.stats as scipy
zscore_list = scipy.zscore(mylist)
[-1.11793077, -0.36479846,  0.31772769,  1.61217384, -1.17676923, 0.72959692]
```

However, when I calculate the same data manually, I get a different result:

```
import statistics as stats
for x in mylist:
`print(str((x-stats.mean(mylist))/stats.stdev(mylist)))`
```

Result:

```
-1.0205264990693814
-0.33301391022264026
0.29004437341971895
1.471706635500054
-1.074238420073032
0.6660278204452793
```

I have tried various things to address the issue, including converting "mylist" into a numpy array, using axis=None and ddof=0 in the call to "scipy.zscore", and nothing changes the result.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: So I figured it out, and figured I would leave this up for anyone interested.

There are two ways to calculate standard deviation: the *population* standard deviation, which divides the sum of the squared differences in the mean by the population size *N*, or the *sample* standard deviation, which divides the sum of the squared differences in the mean by the sample size *n-1*.

As it turns out, NumPy (and hence SciPy) uses the population standard deviation by default. This is rarely appropriate; for most applications where one is inferring population-level stats by drawing on a sample, the sample standard deviation is more appropriate. To correct this, I set `ddof=1` in my call to scipy.stats.zscore, and that solved the problem of incorrect calculation.

I hope this is helpful to someone!